# Define a rectangular bookmark area/container in a Word 2010 template?

Tags: templates, automation, ms-word, bookmarks

In a Word 2010 template (.dotx or .dotm), I want to define a rectangular area/container where I will later insert an image through Word Automation. Thus, the container should serve as boundaries for the inserted (scaled) image.

Can this be done?

One idea is to add dummy images that will later be replaced. Though, I'm not sure how to put the images inside bookmarks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use the "Insert Frame" command in Word 2010 and then place a bookmark inside of it. Then from automation, the size of the frame is read and the image is scaled to fit the frame.